# When to use curly braces and when angle in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props, high-order-component

For example:

```
function Avatar(props) {
  return (
    <img className="Avatar"
      src={props.user.avatarUrl}
      alt={props.user.name}
    />
  );
}

function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Comment">
      <div className="UserInfo">
        <Avatar user={props.author} />
        <div className="UserInfo-name">
          {props.author.name}
```

Why can't I use {Avatar(props.author)} or {Avatar() user={props.author}}? I know that I can use functions inside curly bracets, how it works?

Comment: Because you don't want just call `Avatar` as a function, you want to create a React component, and React won't register it as a component if you just call a random function. You can use `React.createElement` method if you really determined to call something (see https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html for more details)

Comment: I've transform my function into arrow function and now it works perfectly.

Moreover, I've found an article, which says that: Directly calling functional components as functions instead of mounting them using React.createElement is much faster.
I am confused even more.

Comment: That's the point of JSX, to give you an HTML-like syntax so your code is easier to read. You are [by no means forced](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) to use JSX, though.

Comment: @AndrewKruglik if you call `Avatar` as a function it will just inject some elements into the parent component, but it itself will not be registered as a component, so it won't be able to have state or use hooks. And yes, it is faster than `React.createElement` because you skip creating React component.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer: declaring function as `<Component/>`, makes it visible to React and allow you to use lifecycle methods and hooks. If you use it as function: React only see the result that returns from it, but it works ~45 times faster.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the child receive props and return `jsx` it will be considered as React Element or React Node, in this case you can use it like `<Avatar user={props.author} />`.

If you want to use functions inside `Comment` simply like this:

```
function renderAvatar(author) {
     return ...
}
```

`Comment` Component

```
   <div>
      {renderAvatar(props.author)}
   </div>
```